# Editing bash autocomplete to ignore automatically generated files

Tags: bash, command-line, autocomplete

Essentially, if I have a number of files with the same name, except for their extensions, is there a way to make the auto-complete ignore/prioritise specific extensions when I am opening them in the terminal with a text editor.

For example, I have a number of latex documents, and if I wish to open them with vim (say it is work.tex), then even if this is the only tex file in the directory, there will also be work.log, work.aux etc. So I input `vim w` then auto-complete to `vim work.` then I need to add a t to complete `vim work.t` to `vim work.tex`. So in this example if I could the auto-complete to go straight to foo.tex, or to ignore foo.log, foo.aux etc, that would solve the issue.

Whilst it is the most minor of issues, the number of times I open blank files called "foo." is getting very annoying.

Comment: Found a possible answer on [superuser.com](http://superuser.com/q/505378/) using: `export FIGNORE=.log:.aux`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the FIGNORE variable in bash:

```
export FIGNORE=.log:.aux  # You can use as many colon-separated values as you like.
```

You can add this line to your bashrc file or load it on demand.

But if you want to customize your autocompletion and give priority to certain extensions over others, you can have a look to this tutorial:
http://fahdshariff.blogspot.de/2011/04/writing-your-own-bash-completion.html